# Script to check if iptables is running is not working

Tags: iptables, bash, scripting, nagios

I have the following simple script to check if iptables is running or not.  Why does it always returns 'OK' no matter what the status is?

```
#!/bin/bash

#IPT='iptables'
SERV='/sbin/service iptables status'
EXPR='Firewall is stopped.'
        if [ "$SERV" = "$EXPR" ]
                 then
                        echo 'Firewall is not Running'
                        exit 2
                else
                        echo 'OK'
                        exit 0
        fi
```

Comment: http://www.eflo.net/VICIDIALforum/viewtopic.php?p=71701 perhaps of interest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The init script for iptables will never return exactly that string; it will always have something else in it, and there are also failure conditions which don't match that string at all.

Instead, you should check the exit code from the script, as it (on EL and Fedora) returns non-zero if the firewall is not active and zero if it is active.

```
/sbin/service iptables status >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    echo "All systems go."
else
    echo "Houston, we have a problem."
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

You are setting `$SERV` to equal the literal string value "`/sbin/service iptables status`", you need it to execute the command and store the *result*.  You can verify this by echoing `$SERV`.  As written, it will always evaluate to not-equal.

`SERV=$(/sbin/service iptables status)`

Also, make sure the output is as expected.  My version returns `iptables: Firewall is not running.`  (Yours of course may vary.)

Read more about subshells at the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html).

Answer (score 2):

The scripts is doing what it says.
Bear in mind that [ "$SERV" = "$EXPR" ] is comparing *strings* , and they are non-equal.

So, exit status of test will be always non-zero, so will go always to "else".

What you need is to use *Command Subtitution*, instead of SERV='/sbin/service iptables status' you should use either

```
SERV="$(/sbin/service iptables status)"
```

or

```
SERV=`/sbin/service iptables status`
```

HTH

Comment: Backticks work, but it's worth mentioning that `$()` is considered best practice in modern versions of bash for legibility and nesting purposes.

Comment: Indeed, and $() has more variable-alike format